# Verify method call with implicit default value

Tags: scala, mockito

I'd like to understand some behavior using Mockito and Scala's default parameters.

Here is a minimal example:

```
trait SomeImplicit

object SomeService {
  val AnyImplicit = new SomeImplicit {}
}

trait SomeService {
  def doWork(param: String)(implicit di: SomeImplicit = SomeService.AnyImplicit)
}
```

Let's call the `doWork` method:

```
class SomeService$Test extends WordSpec with MockitoSugar {
  "SomeService" should {
    "doWork" in {
      val dodo = mock[SomeService]
      val expectedParameter = "ok"

      dodo.doWork(expectedParameter)

      verify(dodo, times(1)).doWork(expectedParameter)(SomeService.AnyImplicit)
      verifyNoMoreInteractions(dodo)
    }
  }
}
```

Spontaneously, I'd have though it would work. But is does not. I get:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
someService.doWork(
    "ok",
    SomeService$$anon$1@264c1c97
);
-> at SomeService$Test$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SomeService$Test.scala:25)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
someService.doWork(
    "ok",
    null
);
-> at SomeService$Test$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SomeService$Test.scala:23)

Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
someService.doWork(
    "ok",
    SomeService$$anon$1@264c1c97
);
-> at SomeService$Test$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SomeService$Test.scala:25)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
someService.doWork(
    "ok",
    null
);
-> at SomeService$Test$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SomeService$Test.scala:23)
```

Comment: If you look at implementation of `DummyImplicit.dummyImplicit` you'll see this: `implicit def dummyImplicit: DummyImplicit = new DummyImplicit`. So, every time it is called you get a new object. You probably need to pass exact same object(`SomeService.Dummy`) when calling `dodo.doWork(expectedParameter)`, i.e. `dodo.doWork(expectedParameter)(SomeService.Dummy)`.

Comment: If you don't pass implicit parameter, Scala will insert one for you(from `scala.Predef.DummyImplicit#dummyImplicit`)

Comment: Ok, I took a bad example. I updated it with something that is not predefined.

Comment: This looks like it should work to me.

Comment: I totally agree: it should work :) And I cannot find out why it does not...

Answer (score 1):

An implicit parameter with a default value tells the compiler: if the implicit is not found by the usual implicit search process, use this value instead of emitting a compilation error.

`DummyImplicit` is always found in the first step (using `Predef.dummyImplicit`), so the default value is never used.

Comment: Alright, I made a wring example then. I'll update my question with something else than the DummyImplicit. Thanks for pointing that out, by the way.